# Knockout sortable - disseapring elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, mapping, jquery-ui-sortable

When I use "sortable" inside "foreach" binding, moving elements make them disappear. What's more, array position is being updated!

```
<div id="main">
<div data-bind="foreach: tasks">
    <div class="item" data-bind="sortable: $data">
        <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/hw9B2/492/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your viewmodel.

html:

```
<div id="main">
    <div data-bind="foreach: tasks">
        <div class="item" data-bind="sortable: tasks">
            <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

viewmodel:

```
var Task = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var InternalTasks = function(tasks) {
    this.tasks = ko.observableArray(tasks); 
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    var tasks1 = new InternalTasks([
        new Task("Get dog food"),
        new Task("Mow lawn"),
        new Task("Fix car"),
        new Task("Fix fence"),
        new Task("Walk dog"),
        new Task("Read book")
    ]);
    var tasks2 = new InternalTasks([
        new Task("aa"),
        new Task("bb"),
        new Task("cc"),
        new Task("dd"),
        new Task("ee"),
        new Task("ff")
    ]);
    this.tasks = ko.observableArray([tasks1, tasks2]);
};

ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(new ViewModel()));
```

Comment: Yeah, but it is not a solution. I need to create variable number of columns, that each is sortable.

Comment: Maybe is working, but I don't need a single sortable list (I know how to do it), so it is completely not helpful.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and in the next time, please carefully describe your questions.

Comment: Ok, that answer works. I think, my question was described properly - if didn't have to use sortable in foreach, I wouldn't post it. Thanks!